# Why `interaction` is changed(*) from error_stop_mode to scroll_mode right before exiting TeX?

Tags: tex-core

Consider the following two extracts from `tex.web`:

```
  interaction:=scroll_mode; jump_out;
```

```
"X":begin interaction:=scroll_mode; jump_out;
```

I can't understand the reason behind `interaction:=scroll_mode`.

For reference, here are values of `interaction`:

```
batch_mode 0 
nonstop_mode 1 
scroll_mode 2 
error_stop_mode 3
```

**(*)** the value of `interaction` is always `error_stop_mode` right before above code
is executed, because of the following code in `tex.web`:

```
if interaction=error_stop_mode then @<Get user's advice and |return|@>;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is (one might guess) there to ensure you don't get further error interaction after `x`.

But it isn't obvious how you can get a tex error at that point. Fortunately tex.web gives a clue...

```
@ Here we do whatever is needed to complete \TeX's job gracefully on the
local operating system. The code here might come into play after a fatal
error; it must therefore consist entirely of ``safe'' operations that
cannot produce error messages. For example, it would be a mistake to call
|str_room| or |make_string| at this time, because a call on |overflow|
might lead to an infinite loop.
@^system dependencies@>

Actually there's one way to get error messages, via |prepare_mag|;
but that can't cause infinite recursion.
@^recursion@>
```

And in fact if you process this plain tex document in the default error stop mode

```
\mag=2000


aaa

\break

\mag=3000 aaaa\zzzz


\bye
```

and respond to the unknown command error with `x`  then in the log you will see

```
? x
! Incompatible magnification (3000);
 the previous value will be retained (2000).
```

where the incompatible mag error was processed in scroll mode  without the normal interaction